# Div resize on separator's drag and drop without jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to implement separator which should be capable to resize the div on drag and drop. I have tried but my code is not working as expected. Below is my code

**HTML**

```
<html style="overflow-y: hidden!important;" >
   <head>       
<meta name="description" content="Separator">
   </head>
   <body >
      <div id="container" >
         <div id="div1" >As of 2016 the WHO website on environmental health states "Environmental health addresses all the physical, chemical, and biological factors external to a person, and all the related factors impacting behaviours. It encompasses the assessment and control of those environmental factors that can potentially affect health. It is targeted towards preventing disease and creating health-supportive environments. This definition excludes behaviour not related to environment, as well as behaviour related to the social and cultural environment, as well as genetics."[2]

The WHO has also defined environmental health services as "those services which implement environmental health policies through monitoring and control activities. They also carry out that role by promoting the improvement of environmental parameters and by encouraging the use of environmentally friendly and healthy technologies and behaviors. They also have a leading role in developing and suggesting new policy areas
        </div>

         <div class="separator"></div>

         <div id="div2" >As of 2016 the WHO website on environmental health states "Environmental health addresses all the physical, chemical, and biological factors external to a person, and all the related factors impacting behaviours. It encompasses the assessment and control of those environmental factors that can potentially affect health. It is targeted towards preventing disease and creating health-supportive environments. This definition excludes behaviour not related to environment, as well as behaviour related to the social and cultural environment, as well as genetics."[2]

The WHO has also defined environmental health services as "those services which implement environmental health policies through monitoring and control activities. They also carry out that role by promoting the improvement of environmental parameters and by encouraging the use of environmentally friendly and healthy technologies and behaviors. They also have a leading role in developing and suggesting new policy areas</div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
var oSeparator = document.querySelector(".separator"),
  oPrevEl = oSeparator.previousElementSibling,
  oNextEl = oSeparator.nextElementSibling;

    var iIniSepTop;
    var iIniNextElHeight;
    var bDrag = false;

function dragStart(oEvent) {  
  if(oEvent.target == oSeparator) {
    bDrag = true;
    iIniSepTop = oEvent.clientX - oPrevEl.offsetTop;
    iIniNextElHeight = oNextEl.style.height;
  }  
}
function dragEnd(oEvent) {
  bDrag = false;  
}
function drag(oEvent) {  
  if(bDrag){
    oEvent.preventDefault();    
    var iXDiff = iIniSepTop - oEvent.clientX;
    oPrevEl.style.height = oEvent.clientX - oPrevEl.offsetTop;
    oNextEl.style.height = iIniNextElHeight + iXDiff;
  }  
}

oSeparator.addEventListener("mousedown", dragStart, false);
oSeparator.addEventListener("mouseup", dragEnd, false);
oSeparator.addEventListener("mousemove", drag, false);
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#container {
  height: 100%;
}
.separator {
  height: 5px;
  background-color: grey;
  cursor: n-resize;
  position: relative;
}
.separator:hover {
  background-color: #5d5c5c;
}
#div1,#div2 {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto !important;
  position: relative;
  height: 50%; 
}
```

[JS Bin link for the above code](https://jsbin.com/cahazet/edit?html,css,js,output)

*Please do not suggest jQuery UI or any other plugin, because I have been using the same and I don't want to use it to reduce overall code size and also I don't find judicial to use the same only for this one functionality in the whole application.*

It's not working as expected (Div's height should be resized and adjusted with page's relative height on separator's drag and drop).

Comment: have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/JerryGoyal/T4St6/704/

Comment: @AnkushJain gone through it but not able to find out my mistake.